# How to pass information between two activities?

Tags: android-intent, android

I have two activities, *Second* and *Third*.  In the *Second* activity I have two radio buttons, Red and Blue, which the user will be able to use to control the text colour in the *Third* activity. I used an intent and `putExtra()` but it didn't function the way I expected.

Second Activity:

```
public class Second extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_btn3);

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Second.this, Third.class);
        RadioButton redButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.color_red);
        RadioButton blueButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.color_black);
        myIntent.putExtra("check_red", redButton.isSelected());
        myIntent.putExtra("check_blue", blueButton.isSelected());
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }});    
}
```

Third activity:

```
public class Third extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);

        TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        boolean red_check = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("check_red");
        resultView.setText(""+red_check); //for testing. what I got is FALSE
    }
}
```

Comment: red_check key is not the same as check_red.. keys for putExtra and getExtra need to be the same.

Comment: You're putting the value in as "check_red" then trying to read it out as "red_check".

Comment: Sorry about the typo! I updated my code and still getting the same results

Comment: I found the problem.

Instead of using isSelected(), I should use isChecked() instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `isSelected();` calls to `isChecked();`

`isSelected()` has an entirely different meaning than `isChecked();`